# Changing database content with raw SQL brings EntityFramework context out of sync

Tags: entity-framework-core, rawsql

I have a table A that has a foreign key relation to another table B. First I delete an entry (a) in A using raw SQL. Later I delete an entry in table B, b, which was the entry that a was pointing to. When I do this, EntityFramework fails with the error message:

> The association between entity types 'B' and
>   'A' has been severed but the relationship is either
>   marked as 'Required' or is implicitly required because the foreign key
>   is not nullable.

I assume that it is because the context gets out of sync with the database. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right in your assumption. When you change data in the database using raw SQL, the context is unaware of these changes. From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/raw-sql):

> Note that any changes made to data in the database using
>   ExecuteSqlCommand are opaque to the context until entities are loaded
>   or reloaded from the database.

You have to tell EntityFramework to update the context from the database. This can be done like this (assuming only the value `req` is deleted by this SQL command):

```
_db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand($"DELETE FROM \"schema_name\".\"table_A\"");
_db.Entry(req).Reload();
```

Comment: What if I have made bulk update with ExecuteSqlRawAsync> How can I sync my dbcontext, please guide me. I am facing issue where new query still fetching old value.